# How to add a non-spring-boot dependency to the pom.xml in a spring-boot project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I have a `Spring Boot` project and I want to use there the dependency to the `ModelMaker`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

If I add it, I get the error message:

```
Save could not be completed. Try File > Save As... if the problem persists.

Reason:
Could not write file pom.xml

details:
Could not write file: D:\...\pom.xml.
D:\...\pom.xml (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
```

The `ModelMapper` does not belong to the standard `Spring Boot` starters, so I cannot add it to `pom.xml` by Spring>Edit Starters

How can I add a non-starter dependency?

Comment: You can edit the `pom.xml` like any text file and add the dependency. No need for fancy tools.

Comment: @Kayaman I cannot. Restart of STS dose not help

Comment: Show your pom.xml, but I think you tried to had something to the starter, the starter is just a helper to generat your pom.xml, add your dependencies directly to th pom.xml (in the right section)

Comment: I use IntelliJ and I added your dependency into two spring boot projects that are already in production. It workwed with no problems.

Comment: @PauloPedroso Thank you, but I use Eclipse.

Comment: @pdem Added. But I don't think it can help. Something is locking the pom.

Answer (score 0):

Today I found the same problem.

If you are using IntelliJ, just right click in the pom.xml, then Maven and then Reimport.